# Существуют ли Dll библиотеки Java пакеты для использования API Вконтакте?

Tags: вконтакте

Если знаете то ссылки дайте.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот интересный [проект на Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/vk4java/). Сразу на странице проекта есть [хороший поучительный пример.](http://code.google.com/p/vk4java/wiki/Example)